# Помогите подправить меню Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Я сейчас начал работать с таким элементом как `Navigation Drawer`. Для своих работ я использую разные ресурсы, и вот мне как-то попалось интересное изображение меню которое находится под строкой состояния и `toolBar`. Вот если делать все стандартными средствами `Android Studio` то наше меню выплывает над всеми элементами экрана, и получается что все прикрывается. Вот у меня возник закономерный вопрос, как сделать что-бы меню при разворачивании находилось под большей частью элементов приложения. Возможно вопрос звучит довольно запутанно и не очень понятно, но постарался по-максимуму выразить свой вопрос, и надеюсь что кто-то уже занимался подобной проблемой.

Comment: Насколько я понял, вам нужен   DriverLayout
  http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/drawerlayout.php

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос..может пример покажете?

Comment: та я бы показал, но мне попалась как-то картинка и не помню уже где видел.